# Assigning soldiers to a room algorithm issue

Tags: java, search, data-structures

So I have a search problem I need to optimize in Java.  Here is the example that exemplifies the issue I am trying to solve.

A soldier arrives at a base and is assigned a housing unit.  Each base has one or more housing units.

Each housing unit has one or more rooms.  Each room has a number of beds in it.  Each room has a priority number (1 being the highest priority).  The number of beds can be different for each room.

The soldier needs to assigned to a room.  He is assigned to the room with the most available beds.  If there are more than one room with the same number of beds, he goes to the room with the higher priority number.

Once the soldier gets assigned to a room, the number of available beds will be updated, of course, and the next soldier in queue will be added using the same process until all the soldiers are assigned rooms.

We don't have to worry if a soldier cannot be assigned to a bed, because there are none available.  Another process takes care of such overflow situations.

My question is what Java data structure implementation would be best to solve this issue of which room the soldier will get assigned to?

Currently I am using a multi-dimensional ArrayList and feel that there must be a better way.

[image: VisualGraph]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Here is my current thought process of how to solve the issue:
1)  have an array of housing units.  Find the housing unit in the array, O(n).
2)  Each housing unit has an array of rooms.  Search the rooms to find the room with the most available beds and highest priority, O(n).

My solution as a big O notation of O(n).  While this is acceptable, I feel that I should be able to get a faster solution somehow using a tree perhaps?  I just am at a bit of a loss on to implement such a tree or other solution.

Comment: I don't think there is any single data structure you can use. But if you want to make most of existing collections (which is not necessarily most elegant solution), you could try Map<String,Housing> at base level (as you get housing unit allocation upfront, so just lookup is needed) and PriorityQueue<Room> at housing level. Then, make Room comparable based on beds*1000+(1000-priority) (1000 is some number guaranteed to be bigger than biggest priority). Then, when you allocate, pull highest priority from queue, update, put it back. You can have secondary Map<name,room> for other lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do better than just multi-dimensional ArrayLists, both in terms of design and in terms of time complexity.

From a design standpoint, you have three containing classes - `Room`, `House`, and `Base`. (also `Soldier`, though for our purposes `Soldier` doesn't need any extra info.)

```
public class Soldier{}
```

First, `Room` is fairly simple. It has to contain `Soldier`s and know how many open rooms it has left

```
public class Room {

    private int totalBeds;
    public final int priority;
    private ArrayList<Soldier> soldiers;

    public Room(int totalBeds, int priority) {
        this.totalBeds = totalBeds;
        this.priority = priority;
        soldiers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean add(Solider s) {
        if(soldiers.size() >= totalBeds) {
            return false;
        }
        return soldiers.add(s);
    }

    public int getRemainingBeds() {
        return totalBeds - soldiers.size();
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return totalBeds <= soldiers.size();
    }
}
```

From there, we need a `House` class. This a priority queue of `Rooms`, and has to be able to add a soldier to a room based on its priority.

```
public class House {

    private final String name;
    private PriorityQueue<Room> rooms;

    public House(String name, Room... rooms) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rooms = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Room>() {
            public int compare(Room a, Room b) {

                //Always prioritize an open room to a full one
                if(a.isFull() && b.isFull()) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (a.isFull()) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (b.isFull()) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    //Now try to get the room with the most available rooms
                    int bedDiff = b.getRemainingBeds() - a.getRemainingBeds();
                    if(bedDiff != 0) {
                        return bedDiff;
                    }
                    return a.priority - b.priority;
                }
           }
       });
       for(Room r : rooms) {
           this.rooms.add(r)
       }
    }

    public boolean add(Soldier s) {
        Room r = rooms.poll();
        boolean ok = r.add(s);
        rooms.add(r);
        return ok;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Finally, the `Base` class should use a `Map<String, House>` to quickly locate a house by its name

```
public class Base {

    private Map<String, House> houses;

    public Base(House... houses) {
        houses = new HashMap<>();
        for(House h : houses) {
            houses.put(h.getName(), h);
        }
    }

    public boolean add(String houseName, Soldier s) {
        return houses.get(houseName).add(s);
    }
}
```

Full time complexity of adding a soldier to the base:

```
- Finding the correct House: O(1)
- Adding to the House:
    - Poll: O(log(#rooms in house))
    - Add to room: O(1)
    - Add: O(log(#rooms in house))
```

Comment: Wow, this solutions is fast and simplistic!  I am going to try to implement this  solution for my problem. I have co-worker who thinks he can do it with a tree, but I am not sure it will be better than what you have.  Either way I will post my final solution in the next day or two and pick the best solution.

Comment: So my business requirements ended up changing after talking to my business analyst (that never happens, HAHAHA /s) so I won't be able to post my code that matches my question.  I will be using some of this coding logic to help solve my new requirements.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion:

1. First, you don't need to worry about "Housing Unit", since it never gets into the equation in the decision-making process.
2. Perhaps create a `Room` class that keeps fields for the name/housing unit (eg "A1"), number of beds available, and priority.
3. Create an array of `Room[] rooms` (or the equivalent), and sort it by which is next to take a soldier (#beds and priority).
4. When a soldier comes in, he takes a bed in `rooms[0]`, remove a bed. If the room in now full, remove it from the list.
5. Then take `rooms[0]` and find it's new index by comparing with the `rooms[i]` below it until you find the new index.

Continue this, until `rooms` is empty

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use a `PriorityQueue` using a custom comparator for a `Room` class:

```
PriorityQueue<Room> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Room>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Room a, Room b) {
    int compareByAvailableBeds = Integer.compare(
        b.getAvailableBeds(), a.getAvailableBeds());
    if (compareByAvailableBeds != 0) {
      return compareByAvailableBeds;
    }

    return Integer.compare(a.getPriority(), b.getPriority());
  }
});
```

Now, to assign a soldier to a room, you can take the "lowest" priority `Room`, remove that from the queue, assign the soldier to it, and add it back into the queue:

```
Room room = queue.poll();
room.assign(soldier);  // Assuming this decrements the number of available beds.
queue.add(room);
```

Comment: I never even knew java had a priority queue!  Great suggestion.  I am going to research a bit on <code>PriorityQueue</code> for Java.